# MySQL Query/Connect to eximstats?

Tags: mysql, connectivity

I'm trying to run a report for my clients in real-time. I created a new eximstats user (renamed the old one) with:

```
update mysql.user set password=password("XXXXXXXXX") where user="eximstats";
```

In `mysql.db` I'm showing eximstats user and DB.

My connection:

```
  $exim_connect = new mysqli($exim->host, $exim->user, $exim->password, $exim->db);
```

This is my result with and without a password:

> EXIM Connection failed: Access denied for user 'eximstats'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

Is this even possible? If yes, what I'm I missing?

- cpsrvd 11.52.0.22
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
- PHP extension: mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Few reasons could be:

- one of them - 'eximstats' has other host than @'localhost' in user table
- more than 1 user with same name but different host could also give
  error

try to manual connect to the database with this user credentials and check errors if it will be.

Comment: I'm not clear on another host? [link]http://awesomescreenshot.com/0105emabc0 and like I said I renamed eximstats so there is only one user with the name eximstats

Comment: did You try connect with this user to mysql?

for example:
mysql -u eximstats -p

Do You have full list of user?

and in this case could be good idea, attach my.cnf as well

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. I took an existing account, made a copy and a user of eximstats. I'm not clear on why the other ways didn't work...but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason for that is the `skip-name-resolve` turned `ON`. Only numerical IP addresses are accepted while `localhost` can't be resolved into the `127.0.0.1`. Sure the same problem occurs when DNS service is unavailable and `/etc/hosts` is misconfigured.